# Drawing 2d lights using Shaders?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I was wondering how I could create 2D lights like here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVlYsGOkkyM

And here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSf1MpsWKig

The shadows aren't currently in my interest.
I tried some things but they don't seem to work. So all I currently have is the fragment and the vertex shader with hardly any stuff in it.

Comment: Are you using LWJGL3 or the legacy libraries?

Comment: @LaneSurface LWJGL 2.91 :)

Comment: See the ThinMatrix on Youtube, he does a tutorial on point lights, per-pixel lighting, and also specular lighting. He uses the shader to compute the formula.

Comment: @jthort Already seen it! :) Just not sure how to use it for 2D lightning :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lighting is pretty much the main problem of computer graphics and there are several commonly used ways of achieving lights:

The simpler but limited way is called "foward shading" and the general idea is that you give all the information about lighting (ambient light, light positions and colors ect.) to the shader that renders your geometry and the lighting is computed directly on each surface you render. The limitation is that you can only pass fixed number of lights to the shader.

The other way is called "deferred shading" and it is commonly used in modern game engines. Instead of lighting the geometry when you render it you only collect the relevant data for each pixel of the geometry (position, color, normal ect.) and store it in a framebuffer. Then you can use the data to render as many lights as you want. OGLdev has a nice tutorial for deferred shading, but if you are a beginner you probably want to avoid it as it is quite difficult to set up and is slow on old hardware. http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html

Also the general lighting formula in GLSL is:

```
// Vector from the current pixel to the light
vec3 toLight = (lightpos - pixelpos);

// This computes how much is the pixel lit based on where it faces
float brightness = clamp(dot(normalize(toLight), pixelnormal), 0.0, 1.0);

// If it faces towards the light it is lit fully, if it is perpendicular
// to the direction towards the light then it is not lit at all.

// This reduces the brightness based on the distance form the light and the light's radius
brightness *= clamp(1.0 - (length(toLight) / lightradius), 0.0, 1.0);
// The final color of the pixel.
vec3 finalcolor = pixelcolor * lightcolor * brightness;
// If you have multiple lights multiply the pixel's color by the combined color of all lights
// like:
finalcolor = pixelcolor * (lightcolor1 * brightness1 + lightcolor2 * brightness2);

// Note that some things are clamped to avoid going into negative values
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would ask for you Skype if this wasn't such a popular website, but this should do it! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, probably the easiest way though, would to use the build in methods provided by LWJGL. First, you will need to enable lighting, and then your can call the method `glLight()` to place the specified light.

For example:

```
FloatBuffer position = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
float[] posArray = {0f, 0f, 0f, 1f};
position.put(posArray);
position.flip();

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, position));
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, position2)); // position2's definition not shown
```

**Edit:**Forgot to add the actual light

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for some reason. The light doesn't show at all... I just have a black screen, or a white screen, depending if I call glClearColor. Help? :)

Comment: Also, make sure that you re-add the light every time that you update the screen

Comment: What do you mean? I tried the original code in my update method, and it doesn't show anything... Then I tried adding glLight(GL_LIGHT0, 0, position); at the end...

Comment: Make sure that `glLight()` is called before you render anything else; put it at the top of the update method

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'll make an example when I get home

Comment: Haha that is the only thing I am currently drawing :) I enable light0 and do: glLight(...);

Comment: What were you expecting to light then ;) haha, the lighting applies to objects materials, not the background

Comment: Ohhh hahaha thanks for pointing that out... I will try and render a quad and try it out! :)

Comment: Alright. I rendered the quads white! Now it's showing yellow. Probably because of the light! Now how would I go onto creating something like in the video? Like the gradient effect. The closer an object is to the light the more lit up it is??? Im pretty sure I will ned GLSL for this :)

Comment: Is there any chance you are good with GLSL? Haha I would really use a good example for GLSL lightning since I can't find any for 2D rendering :)

Comment: Sure! I'lol need to get home first, but I'll upload an example one in there (in about 2-3 hours)

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I really appreciate it! I will check it out either today or tomorrow :) It's 10pm my place, looking forward to it!

Comment: Going to sleep! I'll check it out tomorrow :)